# CSS3 scale() causes divs to become pixelated

Tags: css, webkit

I've noticed that when animating CSS3 `scale()` it seems to pixelate every element it's used on.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PD7Vh/2/

In the above example, `scale()` pixelates the center div when you hover over it.

Are my css settings wrong, or is this what `scale()` naturally does?

Here's a screenshot from Chrome on Windows 7:

[image]

Comment: Pixelate? You mean it blows up the circle's pixels instead of drawing a new, smooth circle? On which browser?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986226/when-scaling-an-element-with-css3-scale-it-becomes-pixelated-until-just-after-t

Comment: @MrLister it happens in chrome and safari

Comment: On that jsfiddle and my Chrome it doesn't look pixelated at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is to start your center circle as big as it needs to be, then scale it down as the reference starting point.

Then, on the hover event you scale up to 1, which will preserve the unpixelated center circle.

Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rHZBH/)

Note other settings such as positioning are done due to compensate for these changes.

---

**Status Update:**
Consider instead of using border-radius to make circle, use [**ASCII Character**](http://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+character) of circle or outline
circle:

## **• ○ ☺ ☻ ☼**

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AXBzg/) (Note positions are not calibrated.)

The above characters are essentially TEXT, hence use ***ANY*** CSS2 or CCS3 **text or font property**!

As certain characters become really big they do pixelate so use "***reverse scale***" method for these **characters** as previously answered but note, at least in Firefox, the transitions become expensive when super large fonts are used. Works best with medium to large fonts.

**Tip:** *This ASCII based method **may need** the `width and height properties` for positioning to be realized correctly, so use that if positioning seems broken.*

Comment: To clarify further, since your objective was to originally scale the circle dimension 4 times larger, the starting dimension for the circle size must then be 4 times smaller or 1/4 of the size. That being said, the starting `scale of 0.25` is then realized since it's the decimal equivalent of 1/4.

Comment: Check out the new Status Update in my answer for alternate circle method.