# CSS scaling looks pixeled in Safari

Tags: css

In Safari, an element looks pixeled while it is scaling. When the transition is finished turns sharp. In Chrome it looks sharp the whole time. Take a look at this example: http://codepen.io/siggmus/pen/LxBPWg

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(8);
}
```

How can I make it so the element looks sharp while it is scaling in Safari?

Comment: I expect that would be a performance benefit for Safari (WebKit) while Chrome (Blink) has found a way to manage the performance overhead

Comment: I would think of the `div:hover` as `scale(1)` and the unhovered as `scale(0.2)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318676/css3-scale-causes-divs-to-become-pixelated