# Why does SVG get blurred when scaled under webkit browsers?

Tags: css, animation, svg, webkit

When scaling an SVG image using CSS scale transform, the image gets blurred under Chrome or Safari?

Here is a bit of my code:

```
        #logo {
            animation: cssAnimation 120s infinite;
            -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 120s infinite;
            -moz-animation: cssAnimation 120s infinite;
        }

        @keyframes cssAnimation {
            0% { transform: scale(1) }
            50% { transform: scale(2) }
            100% { transform: scale(1); }
        }
```

Many thanks for any help!

Raphaël

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488179/images-losing-quality-for-second-when-interacting-with-page or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986226/when-scaling-an-element-with-css3-scale-it-becomes-pixelated-until-just-after-t answers your question...

Comment: try using `width` http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/bw0fyu11/

Comment: @Vitorino Fernandes thanks but width made the animation jumpy

Comment: I have to scale a svg logo image 200 times larger and the only solution I got is to use width instead, scale3d won't make any difference.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks a lot War10ck! This article helped me: [when scaling an element with css3 scale, it becomes pixelated until just after the animation is complete. I'm animating an element with a border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986226/when-scaling-an-element-with-css3-scale-it-becomes-pixelated-until-just-after-t)
Using scale3d instead of scale, not going over 1, made the trick!