# Jump at end of CSS transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

When I hover over the div, the .note span fades in. After it fades in, the font-weight seems to suddenly increase (it becomes bolder). I realize that in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuz0u2d8/) there is no image, but it is not required to see my issue.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Cool Effect</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="imageHolder">
        <img src="picture1.jpeg">
        <span class="note">Hello!</span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.imageHolder {
    position: relative;
    top:300px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.note {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

img {
    width: 300;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 250px;
}

.imageHolder:hover .note {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Occurs in Chrome, not in Firefox though.

Comment: You could start by closing your img tag (either <img /> or </img> should work....and I'm checking the other stuff

Comment: You could use `translate3d` to use hardware acceleration in Webkit-based browsers. See: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/

Comment: @QuinnRoundy http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp - Img tags do not require closing.

Comment: the validator failed on that....I guess they need to update the validator :)

Answer (score 4):

Using a 3d transform (ie. using hardware acceleration) fixes lots of these rendering issues.

```
.note {
    ...
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    ...
}
```

[This](http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d) is [well](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/) [documented](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/force-hardware-acceleration-with-translate3d-sometimes.html)

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vuz0u2d8/6/)

---

Alternatively, this also seems to work for your example and may have better browser support...

```
.note {
    ...
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    ...
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vuz0u2d8/16/)

Comment: This works very well. Thanks. Only issue is that the text appears bad quality and a bit grainy? https://jsfiddle.net/vuz0u2d8/17/

Comment: Unfortunately that side-effect is also [well documented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024061/webkit-blurry-text-with-css-scale-translate3d)

Answer (score 0):

Note these changes:

```
.note {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s;             <--
    transition: opacity 0.1s;                     <--
}
```

Although the transition speed is slightly quicker this fixes the problem in the fiddle.