# Blury Images in chrome after transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

We design a website using zoomooz plugin that use transforms like translate scale skew etc. 
everything work fine in some browsers like mozilla, i mean images have their transform and showed very well,but in chrome images after transform become blurry.

[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024061/webkit-blurry-text-with-css-scale-translate3d) is some conversation about this problem. but what about images? how can i show them without blurry effect . this is very important for us to show images with good quality in website.

Example:

[In chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7z0D.png)

[In mozilla fierfox 46.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO9Ri.png)

Comment: Have you tried `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: As [@Doupixel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8038694/4796321) mentioned in his answer, webkit does not treat transformed elements as vectors, so they will loose that quality. If you mean that images become blurry, then they probably have a shitty quality to begin with, so you can't scale them up or whatever. Please improve your question so I can go into the **exact** probem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
img {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0); 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); 
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```